# How MNIST really work?

Tags: python, opencv, canvas, tensorflow, mnist

I am working on a digit detection software and I am need to use the MNIST dataset together with TensorFlow.

To predict the numbers I have to do some pre-processing to the images. There are many scripts on the web which have this step inside (the preprocess) but no one of these, at least all what I have tried for now, do what original documentation speak about.
More or less, all the tutorials are based on a theory: the images have to be 28x28 pixels. Which is ok...Maybe..

The documentation tell this about how the MNIST dataset was made:

> The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size
>   normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect
>   ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the
>   anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the
>   images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass
>   of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point
>   at the center of the 28x28 field.

And at this point, this is what I tried to do at my images, to have a 1:1 ratio between MNIST an my ROI.

I create a blank canvas of 28x28 pixels. I took my image (which could be 17x34, it's an example to say that are all rectangular) and resized it to 20x20, without maintaing the ratio between height and width.
I calculate the center of mass of this new (squared) ROI and then I paste it into the center of my 28x28 canvas, in a way that the center of mass and the center of the canvas match.

[image: 1]

Above there is the original ROI (rectangles as result of cropping process) and below the output of preprocessing. Note: the red square does not exist, it's just to highlight.

These images, passed to TensorFlow, are being recognized well (~96%). These.

I have other numbers...

[image: 2]

The blue ones are being recognized with a low percentage (from a range of 80% to 30%) and the red is not recognized (or recognized wrong with a high percentage).

Example: 5,1,4 are recognized as 7,2,6.

My question is this: what I am doing wrong ? Is the center of mass working good (I am asking this because, for some numbers it traslate the 20x20 ROI down the Y axis and I am correcting this manually) ?

Any help is really welcome and appreciated.

P.S: [here](https://mega.nz/#F!X0wl2BaK!gC9jaVUVwgCq-xvtqJrVQA) you can find some numbers NOT pre-processed so you can test.

P.P.S: I am asking this because, for numbers that it don't recognize, if I move/traslate them by 1/2/3 pixels (really, it's matter of few) up or down, TF work good. Why ?

Comment: The key question here is.. what are you using to recognize them? It is perfectly normal that some images are not recognized by a classifier, so what exactly is your concern here?

Comment: I am doing a call to TensorFlow for each image I have. My concern is: why TF don't recognize the images even if I normalized them ? I am asking this because, for numbers that it don't recognize now, if I move/traslate them by 1/2 pixels (really, it's matter of few pixels) up or down, TF work good.
This is it. I am doing wrong the pre-processing ?

Comment: Tensorflow is the framework the classifier is built upon. I'm asking what kind of classifier you're using (CNN? If so, what architecture? How was it trained?)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not understanding very well. Mainly I am using [this](https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict/blob/master/predict_2.py) with some modifications (ex: deleted imageprepare) to adapt my situation.

Comment: The original code doesn't have 100% accuracy and it makes mistakes even on examples it trained on. The real question you should be asking is if it's making more mistakes on your dataset. For this please run some evaluation on both the original set and on yours and compare the numbers. This is not the activation for the right number, but rather how many examples are correct. If they are close enough, you are doing everything right, that's just the best the model can do for you.